# GC for a WeakReference and StrongReference in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I read some literature on WeakReference in java api docs for Java 7 and tried to test the same with the following

```
    package com.finalize;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

public class WeakRefernceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String x = new String("x1");
        String y = new String("x2");

        Map<String, Object> mw = new WeakHashMap<>();
        mw.put(x, new Object());

        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put(y, new Object());

        x = null;
        y = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5;++i)
        System.gc();

        System.out.println(mw.size());
        System.out.println(m.size());

    }

}
```

When I ran it multiple times, I could see that mw.size() was printed as 0. But I am a bit confused because m.size() is never printed as 0. So basically, I am trying to understand the default GC which ran in this hot spot jvm. So when GC starts to mark the reachable objects and it is run after x and y are set as null, why does it mark the object referred to by y as a reachable one because y has been set as null ? Even if the root variable is set as m, why does GC ever reach the object earlier pointed to by y and declare it as reachable ?

In contrast, what is the detailed sequence of lifecycle changes on x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing the main method on the main thread. The main thread has the variable `m` on its stack. This variable `m` is a reference to the HashMap instance. This HashMap instance has a reference to an array of map entries. The unique map entry contained in this array has a reference to the "x2" key and to the corresponding Object.

So there is a strong reference chain going from a root (the main thread stack) to the object stored in the map. That prevents the GC to collect the object in the map.

```
thread stack -> m -> HashMap -> entries -> entry -> "x2"
                                                 -> Object
```

The same goes for the other map and the other object, **except** it's a WeakHashMap, so since the map key is a weak reference and is the only reference left that points to "x1", the GC is allowed to collect the reference to "x1". And once the GC has collected it, the map removes the corresponding entry from its array.

Comment: Just a question, the chain above reflects entry->x2 instead of entry->y->null which would mean that "x2" can be collected and also the second part of my question was the detailed sequence and I wanted to understand where in the chain the object goes to a ReferenceQueue and what happens then. Apologies if that was not clear from the question.

Comment: You're confused. Just because you set y to null doesn't mean that the key in the hashmap becomes null. When you put y as a key in the map, the map receives a copy of the reference, and stores it in one of its entries. Setting y to null makes y point to nothing, but the entry in the map still references the "x2" string. Java is pass by value.

Comment: You are right, I think I missed a point here. Could you also answer the second half of the question regarding where in the chain the object (pointed earlier by weakreference) goes to a ReferenceQueue and what happens next ? Thanks, I will accept the answer and close it. The reason I am stressing on this is because I may have a linked question to the answer!! But thanks!!

Comment: I have answered it already. The key in the WeakHashMap is a weak reference wrapping the string. Once there is no string reference chain leading to the wrapped string, the GC is allowed to collect it, and the map removes the entries that have bean cleared by the GC.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through your code

- you make a copy of the String `"x2"` and assign this to `y`
- you add the String `"x2"` as a key in `m`
- when you GC, `m` is reachable, as is all it's keys.
- after GC, `m` and all it's keys are retained.